# Rendering dynamic tabs with React.js and Semantic UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

Using `React.js` and `Semantic UI React` I'd like to dynamically create tabs.

When using a `const` representing the array of tab objects, this works fine.

```
const panes = [
            {
                menuItem: 'Record 1',
                render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane>
            }
        ]
...
<Tab panes={panes}/>
```

However, I need these to be dynamically added based on the state variable `source`:

```
getPanes() {
        return this
            .state
            .source
            .map((source) => [{
                menuItem: source.sourceName,
                render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane>
            }])
    }
...
<Tab panes={this.getPanes}/>
```

This results in:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `panes` of type `function` supplied to `Tab`, expected an array.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `this.getPanes` refers to your function definition, it doesn't invoke
   your function. You want the result of your function, should you
   should *invoke* it using parentheses: `this.getPanes()`
2. [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array of elements that is the result of applying your supplied function to each original element. What your really want to return within `.map` is your pane object, not an array of one pane object:

--

```
.map((source) => ({ 
  menuItem: source.sourceName, 
  render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane> 
}))
```